# CPP Error: Dereferencing NULL for link list

Tags: c

Can anyone help me with below errors cuz I can't find where did I go wrong...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *link;
};

int main()
{
  node *head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  head -> data = 99;
```

Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'head'.  Link_list_2

```
head -> link = NULL; 

node* next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
next -> data = 89;
```

Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'next'.  Link_list_2

```
next->link = NULL;
head->link = next;


printf("%d\t%d", head->data,next->data);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/G7bxdfE34. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I think this is a bug in intellisense. I was able to reproduce in msvc 16.7.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead of `node *head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`
this line:

`node *head=new node;`. Same for next.

Explanation: To create dynamic structures (that struct means that you want to create a dynamic list or something similar) you use `new` to allocate that node inside the dynamic memory. This line `node *head=new node;` means "create a node pointer called head that points to a node struct and do it at dynamic memory"

Comment: FYI: You _can_ use `malloc` in C++ (though most often you should not). The main difference between `new` and `malloc` is that `new` will call the datatype's constructor. That is not relevant here.